# Get all design documents in CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

How can I get a list of all design documents in CouchDB? Using a http query, not futon.

Comment: Futon just makes queries against CouchDB over HTTP, it doesn't use any special reserved interfaces :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This is the exact query Futon does internally:

```
GET /dbname/_all_docs?startkey="_design/"&endkey="_design0"&include_docs=true
```

Comment: If you want *just* a list of design docs then drop &include_docs=true

Answer (score 8):

New answer for an old question.  From v2.2, you can query the _design_docs endpoint for a database:  See the [docs](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-design-docs) for deatils, but as a simple example:

```
GET /dbname/_design_docs
```

Parameters to the endpoint are consistent with other bulk APIs, like _all_docs.

Answer (score -2):

Exists for powershell a module than simply all operation with CouchDB: [PSCouchDB](https://github.com/MatteoGuadrini/PSCouchDB)

With this command retrieve all design docs in a specific database. To view full request, use *-Verbose* parameter:

```
Get-CouchDBDatabaseDesignDocument -Database test
```